# Getting a warning: A promise was created in handler but was not returned from it, even after returning it

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
isAuthenticated() {
    return compose()
  // Validate jwt
  .use(function(req, res, next) {
    // allow access_token to be passed through query parameter as well
    if (req.query && req.query.hasOwnProperty('access_token')) {
      req.headers.authorization = 'Bearer ' + req.query.access_token;
    }
    validateJwt(req, res, next);
  })
  // Attach user to request
  .use(function(req, res, next) {
    User.findById(req.user._id)
      .exec()
      .then(user => {
        if (!user) {
          return res.status(401).end();
        }
        req.user = user;
        return next();
      })
      .catch(err => { console.log(err); next(err) });
  });

 }
```

I am writing a piece of composable middle ware and the `.then` for the `User.findById` throws the following error `Warning: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it`. why does this happen? I return the `next();` and if the user is not found i also return.

Comment: `validateJwt` is not returned from first `.use()` call?

Comment: Returning it didn't solve the issue sadly.

Comment: What is the line number displayed by the warning?

Comment: It literally doesn't show a line number, very annoying. Take a look. https://gyazo.com/9d56de0195cd573bafa8e2a3fa03f720

Comment: Have you tried returning `User.findById(req.user._id)` ?

Comment: Yes. as you can see it is the only promise that is created in the entire ?`isAuthenticated` function. The error is coming from inside it the `.then`.